# Finding words containing different characters from the word list

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, word-list

I have a word list containing 50,000 words, and I also have a txt file that finds the alphabet character line by line. I am trying to find the words containing 7 different letters by reading the words in the word list in order, and I wrote a method for this.

First, I browse the words and sync a character list, then I check each other in the word by navigating the alphabet txt file and increase the `counter` if there is. In this way, I try to understand how many different letters are in the words and at the end, if it provides control, I add it to the list.

`WordListReader` , read the txt files and return `HashSet`.

But it doesn't work that way and returns an empty list. I couldn't find the problem. How can I do that?

```
public class Pangram {

    // Method
    public HashSet<String> getPangramList(HashSet<String> wordList) throws IOException {
        // Path Alphabets Text File
        String alphabetPath = "alphabet.txt";


        // Array List and Pangram Word List
        ArrayList<Character> allLetters = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList <Character> ch = new ArrayList<>();
        HashSet<String> pangramList = new HashSet<>();
        // Characters List
        char [] allLettersCharList;
        char [] alphaCharacters;

        // Alphabets Text Files Reader
        WordListReader wordListReader =  new WordListReader(alphabetPath);
        HashSet<String> alphabetSet = wordListReader.wordReader();
        Iterator<String> itr = alphabetSet.iterator();

        // Word List
        Iterator<String> iterator = wordList.iterator();

        // Iterator
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            // Words
            String pangramWord = iterator.next();
            // Array List Characters
            allLettersCharList = pangramWord.toCharArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < pangramWord.length();i++){
               ch.add(allLettersCharList[i]);
            }
            int counter = 0;
            while (itr.hasNext()){
                String alphabet = itr.next();
                alphaCharacters = alphabet.toCharArray();

                if(ch.contains(alphaCharacters[0])){
                    allLetters.add(alphabet.charAt(0));
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if(counter == 7){
                pangramList.add(pangramWord);
            }
        }
        return  pangramList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your description of the problem is obscure. Are you looking for all words with exactly 7 different letters ?

Comment: Please include sample contents of *alphabet.txt* - I have no idea what `a txt file that finds the alphabet character line by line` may be. What's wrong with `final static int JACKPOT = 7; if (pangramWord.codePoints().toSet().size() == JACKPOT) pangramList.add(pangramWord);`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood your code but it looks like you do not empty the ‘ch’ variable on each loop round.